# data-bind is not working in jquery

Tags: knockout-2.0

I must not be using jsfiddle correctly.  Because I am having problems with a more complex project I have decided to go back to the intro and see if there is something I missed.
I am using PluralSight videos to get up to speed with knockout.

In the intro demo Steve Michelotti has a fiddle in which he is binding data in jquery prior to adding knockout.  I can't seem to get this binding to work.  The fiddle is here

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/SapphireGirl/Bdr55/2/
```

This is a very simple example and I would expect to see the 
Hello, bob in the run box but the name is not binding the the text in the view model even in jquery like it is shown in the demo.

He is using jquery 1.7 while I am using jquery 2.0
Why won't my name bind?
Something silly I am sure.

javascript:

```
 $(function(){
var viewModel = {
    name: "bob",
    changeName: function() {
        this.name = "steve";

    }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

});

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> In the intro demo Steve Michelotti has a fiddle in which he is binding data in jquery prior to adding knockout. I can't seem to get this binding to work.

but in your code sample you're explicitly referencing `ko` - the Knockout object.

The problem is that you want to use both JQuery and Knockout - so far you've chosen 'JQuery 2.0' as the framework for your page, but you haven't loaded Knockout anywhere.

Go to the 'External Resources' section on the left, and paste 'http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js' (one of the Knockout CDN urls - from their [download page](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/)) and press the '+' to add it to your jsfiddle.

Press 'Run' and now everything should work.

Comment: Thank you @Nate.  I added knockout as an external resource and now the knockout binding is working so I do see the name bound to the span.  And when I make the name an observable and click the changeName button I do see, as expected, Hello, steve .  Also, isn't knockout dependent on jquery so if I use the framework of knockout 2.0 wouldn't I get jquery too?  So instead of adding an external framework I thought I should just be able to use the knockout framework, right?

Comment: @SapphireGirl - Nope, Knockout isn't dependent on JQuery - you have to add them both.